# Getting Error during training: shape of the new value and previous value must match

Tags: typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I encountered this error while training new models in Tensorflow.js. Here is a way to reproduce it in TypeScript:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';

const run = async () => {
  const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.001);

  const input1 = tf.input({
    shape: [ 2 ]
  });
  const out1 = tf.layers.dense({
    units: 1,
    name: 'out1',
    activation: 'tanh'
  }).apply(input1) as tf.SymbolicTensor;
  const model1 = tf.model(
    {
      inputs: input1,
      outputs: out1
    }
  );
  model1.compile(
    {
      optimizer,
      loss: 'meanSquaredError'
    }
  );
  await model1.fit(tf.ones([8, 2]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
    batchSize: 4,
    epochs: 1
  });

  const input2 = tf.input({
    shape: [ 2 ]
  });
  const out2 = tf.layers.dense({
    units: 2,
    name: 'out2',
    activation: 'tanh'
  }).apply(input2) as tf.SymbolicTensor;
  const model2 = tf.model(
    {
      inputs: input2,
      outputs: out2
    }
  );
  model2.compile(
    {
      optimizer,
      loss: 'meanSquaredError'
    }
  );
  await model2.fit(tf.ones([8, 2]), tf.ones([8, 2]), {
    batchSize: 4,
    epochs: 1
  });
};

run();
```

When the second model starts training this error is displayed: **Error: shape of the new value (2,2) and previous value (2,1) must match**

While both models are defined correctly, the error is due to same instance of optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent this error you should instantiate each optimizer separately:

```
model1.compile(
  {
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.001),
    loss: 'meanSquaredError'
  }
);

model2.compile(
  {
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.001),
    loss: 'meanSquaredError'
  }
);
```